# TextInput prompt display does not show correct embedded font

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flex-spark

I have a TextInput that is using an embedded font. The prompt however does not show the correct font.

Comment: Please refer below link... you can get logic to solve your problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11772696/flex-4-6-embedded-fonts-not-applied-to-textfield/11774049#11774049

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set the fontStyle to normal or italic:

```
s|TextInput:normalWithPrompt
{
    fontStyle:normal;
}
```